# Create High-charts graph dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I have created a highchart graph on some time-series data with some custom events in AngularJS. My purpose is, user can change the type of a graph, view or hide a graph with the custom buttons. 
   For the first time it behaves fine. But if I change the time range, and call the same event to generate the HighChart, the graph is plotted but the custom events fails with

```
Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined
```

Again if I call the chart.redraw() method (i.e. case 'redraw'), It is not plotting the graph but updates The Y-Axis.

here is my code snippet

```
$scope.createHighChart = function(){
      var timeSeriesArray = timeSeries($scope.startingDate, $scope.endingDate, $scope.frequency.value);
      var xAxisArray = xAxis(timeSeriesArray)[0];
      var yAxisArray = yAxis($scope.graphTagArray);
      var SeriesArray = Series($scope.graphParameter, yAxisArray, timeSeriesArray.length);
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = "";

    var chart = new Highcharts.chart({
          chart: {
              zoomType: 'xy',
              renderTo: 'container'
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Analytical Graph'
          },
          subtitle: {
              text: ''
          },
          xAxis: xAxisArray,
          yAxis: yAxisArray,
          tooltip: {
              shared: true
          },
          legend: {
              layout: 'vertical',
              align: 'left',
              x: 80,
              verticalAlign: 'top',
              y: 55,
              floating: true,
              backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
          },
          series: SeriesArray
      }, function(chart){
          $(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
              var el = e.currentTarget;
              if(el.hasAttribute("id")){
                var id = el.getAttribute("id").split("_")[0];
                var property = el.getAttribute("id").split("_")[1];             
                var chartIndex = parseInt(id) - 1;
                console.log("********" + chart + "********");
                switch (property) {                  
                  case 'view':
                      var series = chart.get(parseInt(chartIndex) + 1); // id of my Series
                      series.setVisible(!series.visible);
                      break;
                  case 'spline':
                      chart.series[parseInt(chartIndex)].update({ // index in my Series
                        type: 'spline',
                        dashStyle: ''
                      });
                      break;
                  case 'dotted':
                      chart.series[parseInt(chartIndex)].update({
                        type: 'spline',
                        dashStyle: 'shortdot'
                      });
                      break;
                  case 'column':
                      chart.series[parseInt(chartIndex)].update({
                        type: 'column'
                      });
                      break;
                  case 'area':
                      chart.series[parseInt(chartIndex)].update({
                        type: 'area',
                        dashStyle: ''
                      });
                      break;
                  case 'areaspline':
                      chart.series[parseInt(chartIndex)].update({
                        type: 'areaspline',
                        dashStyle: ''
                      });
                      break;
                  case 'redraw':
                      /** Creating  all the datas**/
                      var timeSeriesArray = timeSeries($scope.startingDate, $scope.endingDate, $scope.frequency.value);
                      var xAxisArray = xAxis(timeSeriesArray)[0];
                      var yAxisArray1 = yAxis($scope.graphTagArray);
                      var SeriesArray = Series($scope.graphParameter, yAxisArray, timeSeriesArray.length); 

                      chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(xAxisArray, true);
                      chart.xAxis[0].isDirty = true;

                      chart.yAxis[0].setCategories(yAxisArray1, true);
                      chart.yAxis[0].isDirty = true;

                      var newDataArray = Series($scope.graphParameter, yAxisArray, timeSeriesArray.length);                      
                      console.log("newDataArray", newDataArray);
                      chart.addSeries(newDataArray);
                      chart.redraw();
                  default:
                    if(series){
                      series.setVisible(true);
                      chart.series[parseInt(chartIndex)].update({
                        type: 'column',
                        dashStyle: ''
                      });
                    }                      
                } 
              }                            
          });
      });
    };
```

[image: The Default Picture, ie: high-chart created for the first time with **$scope.createHighChart()**]

[image: the Graph created with the **case redraw: **]

Comment: Can you make a live example of the issue, .e.g. on jsfiddle/plunkr/etc.? Your starting point can be this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/46rhz/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your approach, I had solved the issue by jQuery.I had  use $(document).Off('click', 'a') before $(document).on('click', 'a')